# How to make threads in ExecutorService to wait stage

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, java-stream, executorservice

In my web application, I need to call around more than 10 methods in one API call. To make that efficient I use `ExecutorService` to create multiple threads at a same time. Each methods returning different Objects expect `fav_a(), fav_b(), fav_c()`. (Sample code is given below for easiness)

```
@GetMapping(RequestUrl.INIT)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, List<?>>> init() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);

    Future<List<Object>> method_a = service.submit(() -> someService.method_a());
    Future<List<Object>> method_b = service.submit(() -> someService.method_b());
    Future<List<Object>> method_c = service.submit(() -> someService.method_c());       
    
    Future<List<FavouriteConverter>> fav_a = service.submit(() -> someService.fav_a());
    Future<List<FavouriteConverter>> fav_b = service.submit(() -> someService.fav_b());
    Future<List<FavouriteConverter>> fav_c = service.submit(() -> someService.fav_c());

    service.shutdown();

    List<FavouriteConverter> combinedFavourite = Stream.of(fav_a.get(), fav_b.get(), fav_c.get()).flatMap(f -> f.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    combinedFavourite=combinedFavourite.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(FavouriteConverter::get_id, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .limit(25)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Map<String, List<?>> map = new HashMap<>();    

    map.put("method_a", method_a.get());
    map.put("method_b", method_b.get());
    map.put("method_c", method_c.get());
    map.put("favourite", combinedFavourite);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

First I need to get `fav_a.get(), fav_b.get(), fav_c.get()` to make `combinedFavourite`. If any of one delays, the logic will be wrong. Creating threads are expensive.

1. Does `Stream` automatically handle this kind of situation?
2. If `fav_a(), fav_b(), fav_c()` do it jobs earlier than other methods, How can I put `combinedFavourite` into another thread? This means how to make `Future<List<FavouriteConverter>> combinedFavourite` in waiting stage until `fav_a.get(), fav_b.get(), fav_c.get()` finishes. (Assume `method_a(),method_b(),method_c()` still running.)

Answer (score 2):

1. No, Streams are not responsible for joining these threads.
2. Since you wait for the results of these 3 threads and putting them into a map which you return, wrapping such logic in a separate thread doesn't help you as long as you have to wait and return the result.

   Use [`ExecutorService::invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) to execute all the tasks and returning a list of Futures when all are complete (when `Future::done` is `true`).

   ```
   List<Future<List<Object>>> list = service.invokeAll(
       Arrays.asList(
           () -> someService.method_a(),
           () -> someService.method_b(),
           () -> someService.method_c()
   ));
   ```

   Note these are guaranteed:

   - The result `List<Future>` is in the same order as the collection of tasks given (according to its `Iterator`).
   - All the tasks will run in a separate thread if the pooled number of threads are higher or equal than executed tasks (assuming there are no other tasks using a thread from the same thread pool).

This logics helps you to work with complete results.

Comment: Great explanation. Does that mean, I need to use two `invokeAll()` for set `method_a(), method_b(), method_c()` and set `fav_a(), fav_b(), fav_c()`, then using the `isDone()` on  `fav` set where i can assign a thread to do `combinedFavourite` once `fav` set done before shutdowning ?

Comment: Yes, I'd use two `invokeAll()` methods (make the thread pool large enough). You don't need to use `Future::isDone` as long as `invokeAll` waits and guarantees until all the Futures are done (`Future::isDone` will be `true` for all of them). Also note that `ExecutorService::shutdown` actually doesn't shutdown the service immediatelly but rather sends a request to shutdown - it changes the state of the service to something like "shutting down" which means it rejects new tasks but finishes ongoing ones.

Comment: thank you so much, that working fine. Since i need to put all services in map, i can get the result by geting the index of list, no?

Comment: Yes, the order of the result Futures is the same as the tasks.

Comment: Interesting question, @Nikolas I created three threads with different sleep times `Future<String> a= service.submit( ()->{ System.out.println("First third starts"); Thread.sleep(10000); return "First thread"; } );` Then what I did is, `Stream.of(a.get(),b.get(),c.get()).collect(Collectors.toList());` Its returning all three methods results. is Stream blocked by `.get()`??

Comment: Yes, the Stream is blocked until the all the Futures are completed.